# pre build configuration in Hudson

Tags: hudson

I want to do a pre build configuration in hudson. basically I want to run a shell script which changes one perticular file after all the fresh source code is download from svn.
and then build...but hudson is not allowing it..

Comment: What kind of a project do you have?  Is it a Maven 2 build?

Answer (score 1):

Just create the project as a freestyle project and configure the first step to execute the script. The next one to run your build via Maven or whatever. You should add the script to the project in your version control system.

Also check out the Hudson book for more info
http://www.simpligility.com/2011/06/hudson-book-changes-and-community/